# How should I unit-test functions that open local files or download them?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a server class, that fetches files from Internet using `urllib`, and fetches files from the disk drive (`open`). I have several functions, whose jobs are to return an open stream, whether it's an open file, or an Internet resource. How should I unit-test these functions to know that they are returning what they should? Or, in general, how should I unit-test methods that access outside sources (whether it's a database or socket connection)?

Comment: Check out this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199700/python-how-do-i-make-temporary-files-in-my-test-suite). The answers explain how to set up local folders and files during unit testing.

Comment: @JavoSN that can work for files, but what about other cases?

Comment: Same strategy applies. You need to set everything up in a controlled manner. For fetching files, you should enable a temporary http server to serve the files. There are libraries such as [this](https://gist.github.com/glenfant/7369894) (warning: i haven't tried it) to do so.

Comment: @JavoSN wouldn't that be dangerously close to the Integration Test territory?

Comment: You should also look into the [mock library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html)

Comment: Technically, unit testing is testing of the smallest testable units alone, while integration testing involves combining multiple units. If there's no other way to test a method, other than mocking a http server, then this falls within "unit testing" territory. It also depends on your testing process, if you automate tests, you could have to policy to specify how and when you will test these sorts of methods.

Comment: @wpercy could you write this as an answer? I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [mock library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) included in `unittest`.