# How to mock os.listdir to pretend files and directories in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a proprietary repository format and I'm trying to develop a Python module to process these repositories. Repo format goes as:

```
/home/X/
       |
       + alpha/
       |
       + beta/
       |
       + project.conf
```

Here, `X` is a project. `alpha` and `beta` are folders inside this project and they represent *groups* in this project. A *group* is a container in this repo and what it represents is really not relevant for this question. The repo `X` also has files in its root level; `project.conf` is an example of such a file.

I have a class called `Project` that abstracts projects such as `X`. The `Project` class has a method `load()` that builds an in-memory representation.

```
class Project(object):

    def load(self):
        for entry in os.listdir(self.root):
            path = os.path.join(self.root, entry)
            if os.path.isdir(path):
                group = Group(path)
                self.groups.append(group)
                group.load()
            else:
                # process files ...
```

To unit test the `load()` method by mocking the file system, I have:

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock
import Project

class TestRepo(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_load_project(self):
        project = Project("X")

        with mock.patch('os.listdir') as mocked_listdir:
            mocked_listdir.return_value = ['alpha', 'beta', 'project.conf']
            project.load()
            self.assertEqual(len(project.groups), 2)
```

This does mock `os.listdir` successfully. But I can't trick Python to treat `mocked_listdir.return_value` as consisting of files and directories.

How do I mock either `os.listdir` or `os.path.isdir`, **in the same test**, such that the test will see `alpha` and `beta` as directories and `project.conf` as a file?

Comment: Nothing you do to `os.listdir` is going to make other functions think those names name real files and directories. `os.listdir` just spits out a bunch of names.

Comment: I agree with what @user2357112 said. Do you have alpha & beta as directories in the project? If so you really don't need to mock `os.path.isdir`.

Comment: alpha and beta are not part of the project. They are dummy directories to explain the structure of the repository processed by this project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to achieve the desired behavior by passing an iterable to the `side_effect` attribute of the mocked `isdir` object.

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock
import Project

class TestRepo(unittest.TestCase):

  def test_load_project(self):
      project = Project("X")

      with mock.patch('os.listdir') as mocked_listdir:
        with mock.patch('os.path.isdir') as mocked_isdir:
          mocked_listdir.return_value = ['alpha', 'beta', 'project.conf']
          mocked_isdir.side_effect = [True, True, False]
          project.load()
          self.assertEqual(len(project.groups), 2)
```

The key is the `mocked_isdir.side_effect = [True, True, False]` line. The boolean values in the iterable should match the order of directory and file entries passed to the `mocked_listdir.return_value` attribute.

Answer (score 27):

You could use `pyfakefs` ([source](https://github.com/jmcgeheeiv/pyfakefs), [docs](http://jmcgeheeiv.github.io/pyfakefs/release/index.html)), a very handy lib to test operations on a fake file system.

If you use `pytest`, it has a plugin, all file system functions already get patched, you just need to use its `fs` fixture:

```
import os

def test_foo(fs):
    fs.CreateFile('/home/x/alpha/1')
    fs.CreateFile('/home/x/beta/2')
    fs.CreateFile('/home/x/p.conf')    
    assert os.listdir('/home/x/') == ['alpha', 'beta', 'p.conf']
```

or if you prefer `unittest`:

```
import os
import unittest

from pyfakefs import fake_filesystem_unittest
   
class TestRepo(fake_filesystem_unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.setUpPyfakefs()

    def test_foo(self):
        os.makedirs('/home/x/alpha')
        os.makedirs('/home/x/beta')
        with open('/home/x/p.conf', 'w') as f:
            f.write('foo')
        self.assertEqual(os.listdir('/home/x/'), ['alpha', 'beta', 'p.conf'])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

It will depend, of course, on exactly which `os` functions you use, but it looks like [`mock.patch.multiple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch.multiple) on `os` is just what you need.  (Note that you may not need to patch `path`; many of its functions are lexical-only and do not care about the actual filesytem.)