# Python unit testing: temporary directories, multiple tests, and context managers

Tags: python, unit-testing

I've written a small module for work and I'm adding some unittesting. The module writes files that need to be read back in for testing purposes and I'm using `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()`. I create the temporary directory in the `setUp()` method of my test class and tear it down in the `tearDown()` method because clearly, I don't want to trash up the file structure when tests are run in prod. My understanding is that the `setUp` and `tearDown` methods are run before and after each test and while this adds some overhead to the testing process (i.e., each test takes about 0.5 seconds to run), I'm not all that worried about the time.

My test class

```
class MyUtilsTest(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.dir_name = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
        file_name = "file_used_for_testing.pptx"
        self.presentation_path = self.dir_name.name + "/" + file_name

        # Do some things, including writing some stuff to the temporary directory

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        self.dir_name.cleanup()

    def test1(self) -> None:
        self.assertTrue(
            os.path.isfile(self.presentation_path), f"{self.presentation_path} exists."
        )

    def test2(self) -> None:
        prs = Presentation(self.presentation_path)
        self.assertEqual(len(prs.slides), 4)

    def test3(self) -> None:
        prs = Presentation(pptx=self.presentation_path)
        titles = [prs.slides[s].placeholders[0].text for s in np.arange(0, 4)]
        self.assertEqual(
            titles, ["Test title", "Image title", "Table title", "Bullet title"]
        )

    # More tests that rely in files in self.dir_name here
```

When I have my test class set up like this, all of my tests run and pass without issue, but I get a linter warning:

[image: Pop-up linter warning]

I'm new-ish to writing software-like code in Python and in doing research on this linter warning, I ran into several questions on SO (e.g., [Python: How do I make temporary files in my test suite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199700/python-how-do-i-make-temporary-files-in-my-test-suite)). I've tried editing my test class to incorporate using `with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as dir_name:` but when I do this, my tests fail. For example, when I edit the `setup()` method (and remove the `tearDown()`) to

```
def setUp(self) -> None:
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as dir_name:
        file_name = "file_used_for_testing.pptx"
        self.presentation_path = dir_name + "/" + file_name

        # Do some things, including writing some stuff to the temporary directory
```

the later tests can't find the temp directories, I suspect because the temp dir was destroyed after leaving the context/function and prior to the test running.

How can I keep the context manager open for subsequent tests that rely on the files that are produced in the `setUp()` method?

Comment: You can't.  The point of using a context is that it's created and cleaned up in the same block of code, so it's impossible to not clean it up.  I think it's fine to just silence the linter warning, but if you want to use a context, you need to enter and exit the context inside the test function where you actually use the temp dir that it represents  There's no law saying that *all* your setup *needs* to be in the `setUp` function.

Comment: But it's also fine IMO to silence this linter warning in this specific instance.  The `tearDown` should take care of it, and `TemporaryDirectory` cleans itself up on `__del__` even if you forget to clean it up yourself.

Comment: @Samwise This was my suspicion. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need to recreate the directory for each test case, you can override `unittest.TestCase.run()` to customize the behavior of the test execution. [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.run)

For example:

```py
import tempfile, unittest

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def run(self, result=None):
        with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as dir_name:
            self.dir_name = dir_name
            super().run()

    def test(self):
        print(self.dir_name)
        self.assertIsNotNone(self.dir_name)
```